# Seemingly deadlock in WriteFile on stdout

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writing a small application which handles a predefined exchange of messages over the serial port(basically a custom application level protocol).
The main 2 parts of it are a state-machine which defines what to respond to a certain expected message, the stop conditions, timeout of an expected message, etc and an "event loop" which listens (through a blocking call) on a separate thread to the communication events and, when it is awaken, it passes it to the state-machine to be processed. This in turn will make the states to flow and the process is repeated until the final state is reached, at which point the main thread is awaken(which was waiting with a std::cond_var) and joins the thread.

My problem arises when, out of the blue, the calls to the operator<< of cout block the event-loop thread indefinitely. The call stack shows that the thread is waiting in a WriteFile call. It seems to be a deadlock. I'm not very documented about windows API and inner workings, but it seems to be it should obviously not put any potential synchronization problem(deadlocks) to the user, even though it might not work as expected(i understand that not excluding access to that section for stdout at least will result in interleaved messages for example - this is not my problem ).

I have attached 2 printscreens in which i captured the thread stacks shown by Visual Studio. I really believe that there should be no application written is user space, no matter how bad, that would induce a deadlock in console output, which is why i'm not pasting code here.

Searched the web for a day and a half and at this point i don't know how to rephrase the search for google to get some useful info. Even if i did get, don't think i would necessarily know. Could you please point me some directions? Maybe common problems with stdout. Or something really bad i could in my code to cause a deadlock of this sort. Thank you in advance.

[First operator<< sometimes reproduces the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLG9b.png)

[At this point is usually the problem seen. A communication event just came in after a long delay/it timed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W8bI.png)

```
void CSerialConnection::funct(std::tuple<bool, bool, int> args)
{


    bool singleByteExpected = get<1>(args), stopped = get<0>(args);
    unsigned int timeoutValue = get<2>(args);
    bool terminate = false;

    DWORD modemStatus;
    OVERLAPPED osStatus;

    memset(&osStatus, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
    osStatus.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    cout << "Starting communication event loop ... " << endl;

    BOOL fWaitingOnStat = FALSE;
    BOOL bReadStatus = FALSE;

    do
    {
        if (!fWaitingOnStat)
        {
            cout << "Listening for " << (singleByteExpected ? "control character .. " : "command payload .. ") << endl;
            SetCommMask(mHandle, (singleByteExpected ? EV_RXCHAR : EV_RXFLAG ));
            bReadStatus = WaitCommEvent(mHandle, &modemStatus, &osStatus);
        }

        if (bReadStatus)
        {
            cout << "Event occured sync" << endl;
            mProtocol.processEvent(terminate);

            if (terminate)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            {
                fWaitingOnStat = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Communication event failed with code: " << GetLastError() << endl;
                mProtocol.processTermination();
                stopped = true;
            }

            if ( fWaitingOnStat )
            {
                cout << dec << "WAITING FOR " << ( timeoutValue ? timeoutValue : INFINITE ) << endl;

                auto dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(osStatus.hEvent, timeoutValue ? timeoutValue : INFINITE);

                cout << "WAIT ENDED :)" << endl;

                if (dwRes == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                {
                    //cout << "Event occured async" << endl;
                    mProtocol.processEvent(terminate);

                    fWaitingOnStat = false;

                    if (terminate)
                    {
                        mProtocol.processTermination();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (dwRes == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
                {
                    cout << "Timeout" << endl;
                    mProtocol.processTimeout();

                    fWaitingOnStat = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Communication event failed with code: " << GetLastError( ) << endl;
                    mProtocol.processTermination();
                    stopped = true;
                }

            }
        }

        stopped = mProtocol.getStopRequiredFlag();
        singleByteExpected = mProtocol.getWaitingForControlCharFlag();
        timeoutValue = mProtocol.getTimeout();
    } 
    while (!stopped);

    cout << "Stopped communication event loop ... " << endl;
}
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: Please don't downgrade the question for personal preferences. It will most likely kill the visibility. As i stated, this really shouldn't be a matter of coding, but more of how the stdout can get in such a state. Also the images contain a call to operator<< in a the first few lines of main.

Comment: this wont be downvoted for personal preferences, but due to missing code, missing a specific question, including screenshots when it should be text, and possibly more... not my downvote btw, just trying to clarify

Comment: What's on the other end of `stdout`?  If it is redirected to a pipe, it can block until the other end reads.  If it is redirected to a file, it can block waiting for file I/O (which could be very slow if it's on a mounted network drive).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You'll note that it states that `Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.`   On top of that, you'll notice the link `How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.`

Comment: @Vlad Downvoting in this case is not a question of preference. Images are only acceptable when the information they convey couldn't be conveyed in the form of text. Images can't be searched, they can't be compiled to reproduce the problem, they can't be used by the visually impaired readers, etc.In addition, there isn't enough information for a complete answer. The problem doesn't seem obvious from what you submitted, so you will need to provide more details. Consider trying to write a [MCVE]. You might even find the problem yourself in the process.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt  stdout is directed to the console. it is a simple console application. Alternatively, when i tried to redirect the output from cmd to a file, it seems to not block anymore.

Comment: i'm not calling WriteFile explicitly, the implementation of the standard for operator<< is, as it can be seen in the call stack(if im not mistaken)

Comment: On windows, if you select text on the console it blocks io... that would cause the problem you're talking about.

Comment: `I really believe that there should be no application written is user space, no matter how bad, that would induce a deadlock in console output`  You're also wrong here.  It's possible to deadlock new() if you really put some effort into it; so I'd fully expect it to be possible to deadlock a stream

Comment: oh wow... i managed to reproduce/avoid the behavior by selecting/not marking. seems this was it. amazing. why is this the default behavior... thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! As per UKMonkey's suggestion, the behaviour was caused by me marking text on the console window. It consistenly works now if i leave it alone and blocks if i mark a character. I need to change these settings :). Thank you for interest in my question and the answers!